# OutOfMemoryError in Bufferedmutator of HBase

Tags: java, hbase, threadpool

I am getting below error when data insertion in HBase through BufferedMutator,

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread 
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1367) 
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncRequestFutureImpl.sendMultiAction(AsyncRequestFutureImpl.java:547) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submitMultiActions(AsyncProcess.java:337) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:320) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:228) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.doFlush(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:303) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BufferedMutatorImpl.close(BufferedMutatorImpl.java:241)
```

Here I am Inserting data of length 200-300 bytes per request with single Connection. And Synchronized queries are generated. Also find below thread dump. where Timed waiting threads are of htable-pool. 
[Thread Dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PGtD.png)

Can you please answer about how to tackle this Exception.
Sample code -

```
    try(BufferedMutator mutator = Connection.creatConnection().getBufferedMutator(TableName.valueOf(tableName)) {
            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
            map.forEach(element->put.addColumn(CF,element.getKey(),element.getValue());
            mutator.mutate(put);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: @Bsquare Added Sample code in question and input is String map with 100 entries.

Comment: How do you launch your application? What is the configuration of HBase? In particular how many memory? On which OS are you working?

Comment: Simple Java Script is launched by java command From one server to HBase server. HBase have 1 Master and 6 Region servers. At the time of script running server have 25 - 30 GB free memory and running from ubuntu OS.